# Is my react code using port 3000 instead of port 80?

Tags: reactjs, port, protocols

Can somebody explain me how is my react application using port 3000.
I have created a web application in react. By default it uses port 3000 when i run the application. But it is accessing the application over http://localhost:3000.
What does that exactly mean. Is it using http i.e. port 80 and port 3000 simultaneously or is it using 3000 instead of 80.

Comment: port !== protocol

Comment: but http uses port 80 for its connection. how does that work then? Or is it using 3000 for http?

Comment: 80 is just a common port used for web, one could use it for SSH if they see fit it has nothing to do with the http protocol.. if your react app is listening on port 3000 and not on 80 then it using 3000 not 80, and visa-versa. When you do `http://ip:port` its telling the browser to connect to that port, its not doing port 80 and then going to 3000

Comment: Port 80 has Description HTTP on wiki. So it makes sense that when HTTP is specified in URL, it will select port 80 by default. but when we do http://ip.port, how does it handle the request. As there's HTTP in the url, there's port 80 by default, and then we specify a different port. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify package.json file and under scripts you have to change start to this:

```
 "start": “set PORT=8000 && react-scripts start",
```

to change the port. By default it is 3000.

Comment: so does that mean it is using port 3000 for http?